# sort hash of array by value

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I am trying to sort by value in a HoA wherein key => [ a, b, c]
I want to sort alphabetically and have tried and read with no success.  I think its the commas, but please help! Below is a short snippet.  The raw data is exactly how it appears in the data dumper print vs. the CLI. I have to use some sort of delimiter otherwise the cli output is tedious!   Thank you!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $lsvm_a,$lsvm_b,%hashA,%hashB );
my $vscincludes  = qr/(^0x\w+)\,\w+\,\w+.*/;  #/

open (LSMAP_A, "-|", "/usr/ios/cli/ioscli lsmap -vadapter vhost7 -field clientid vtd backing -fmt ," ) or die $!;
while ($lsvm_a = (<LSMAP_A>)) {
     chomp($lsvm_a);
     next unless $lsvm_a =~ /$vscincludes/;
     @{$hashA{$1}} = (split ',', $lsvm_a);
}

open (LSMAP_B, "-|", "/usr/sbin/clcmd -m xxxxxx /usr/ios/cli/ioscli lsmap -vadapter vhost29 -field clientid vtd backing -fmt ," ) or die $!;
while ($lsvm_b = (<LSMAP_B>)) {
     chomp($lsvm_b);
     next unless $lsvm_b =~ /$vscincludes/;
     push @{$hashA{$1}}, (split ',', $lsvm_b);
}


print "\n\nA:";
for my $key ( sort { $hashA{$a} cmp $hashA{$b} } keys %hashA ) {
    print "$key => '", join(", ", @{$hashA{$key}}), "'\n";
}
##
print "===\nB:";
foreach my $key ( sort { (@{$hashB{$a}}) cmp (@{$hashB{$b}}) } keys %hashB ) {
    print "$key ==> @{$hashB{$key}}\n";
}

print "\n\n__DATA_DUMPER__\n\n";
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hashA; print Dumper \%hashB;
```

Output

```
A:
0x00000008 => '0x00000008, atgdb003f_avg01, hdisk10, atgdb003f_ovg01, hdisk96, atgdb003f_pvg01, hdisk68, atgdb003f_rvg01, hdisk8, vtscsi0, atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924'
===
B:
0x00000008 => '0x00000008, atgdb003f_avg01, hdisk10, atgdb003f_data, atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924, atgdb003f_ovg01, hdisk96, atgdb003f_pvg01, hdisk68, atgdb003f_rvg01, hdisk8'

__DATA_DUMPER__

$VAR1 = {
          '0x00000008' => [
                            '0x00000008',
                            'atgdb003f_avg01',
                            'hdisk10',
                            'atgdb003f_ovg01',
                            'hdisk96',
                            'atgdb003f_pvg01',
                            'hdisk68',
                            'atgdb003f_rvg01',
                            'hdisk8',
                            'vtscsi0',
                            'atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924'
                          ]
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '0x00000008' => [
                            '0x00000008',
                            'atgdb003f_avg01',
                            'hdisk10',
                            'atgdb003f_data',
                            'atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924',
                            'atgdb003f_ovg01',
                            'hdisk96',
                            'atgdb003f_pvg01',
                            'hdisk68',
                            'atgdb003f_rvg01',
                            'hdisk8'
                          ]
        };

### CLI out ### 
            ###0x00000008,atgdb003f_avg01,hdisk10,atgdb003f_ovg01,hdisk96,atgdb003f_pvg01,hdisk68,atgdb003f_rvg01,hdisk8,vtscsi0,atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924
        ###0x00000008,atgdb003f_avg01,hdisk10,atgdb003f_data,atgdb003f_data.5bcd027df10f27bf9a880ce7bc1dd924,atgdb003f_ovg01,hdisk96,atgdb003f_pvg01,hdisk68,atgdb003f_rvg01,hdisk8
```

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have read this and the code IS ONE snippet of the entire script.

Comment: By mentioning `MCVE` @GillesQuenot meant to say that you ask about sorting a hash and yet show us a program snippet unrelated to that problem, where the sorting problem has to be fished out.  (While I posted an answer I am still a little unsure of what you need to sort how ... a hash with an arrayref for a value, but which itself has only one element?)

Comment: o sorry.  I honestly did not realize it was one element, but yes I see that now because I am storing it all in $2.

Comment: Alright, cool (thank you for posting code in the first place! :) -- I spelled that out in my answer.  You may wish to edit the question to state clearly what you are trying to sort. But once there's been two answers it's tricky -- you don't want to invalidate them ... perhaps add a section at the end where you can summarize what need be sorted?

Comment: I was able to adjust/edit my code to use split on a comma instead of $2 or $3, etc. and therefore I think I have multiple elements in my HoA, correct?   Maybe not because its still not abc sorting.  see output.  thank you!

Comment: Ah, OK, so you actually have multiple values in those arrayrefs ... (there goes my "answer").  But then what and how do you want to sort?   If it's keys, on what criterion?  Or do you want those arrayrefs sorted?

Comment: sort the arrayref values ideally but i’d like to see both. sort of keys would be the <=> operator.

Comment: you sort arrayref values by `for (keys %h) { @{$h{$_}} = sort @{$h{$_}} }`.  as for keys, what is the criterion to sort them by? just keys themselves? or by values ... how?

Comment: ok thank you!!! when i stringify for a compare, is it better to use a scalar or an array?  #(@val1) = ( @{$hashA{$key}} = sort @{$hashA{$key}} );
    # $val1 = join(",", ( @{$hashA{$key}} = sort @{$hashA{$key}} ));
if ( @val1 eq @val2) OR if ( $val1 eq $val2 )

Comment: If you want to compare two arrays -- whether they are equal element by element -- then forming strings out of them is one way (but there are others, and there are modules to do that).  But saying `@a1 == @a2` only compares their lengths (numbers of elements), since `==` imposes "_scalar context_" in which both arrays are evaluated to their number of elements and then that compared.  (The `@a1 eq @a2` is a strange version of that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**   The arrayrefs (hash values) have multiple elements after all, and need be sorted. Then

```
for my $key (keys %h) { @{$h{$key}} = sort @{$h{$key}} }
```

or, more efficiently<sup>†</sup> (and in the [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) form, with less noise but perhaps less clear)

```
$h{$_} = [ sort @{$h{$_}} ] for keys %h;
```

The [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) by default uses lexicographical sort, as wanted.

Keys are desired to be sorted numerically, but note that while we can rewrite the arrays to make them sorted it is not so with hashes, which are inherently unordered. We can print sorted of course

```
foreach my $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h) { ... }
```

This will warn if keys aren't numbers.

<sup>†</sup> *By 56% – 60% in my benchmarks on three different machines, with both v5.16 and v5.30.0*

---

*Original post*

I take it that you need to sort a hash which has an arrayref for a value, whereby that arrayref has a single element. Then sort on that, first, element

```
foreach my $key ( sort { $hashB{$a}->[0] cmp $hashB{$b}->[0] } keys %hashB ) {
    print "$key ==> @{$hashB{$key}}\n";
}
```

See the `cmp` operator under [Equality operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).  It takes scalars, which are stringwise compared (so the attempted sorting with an array from the question is wrong since `cmp` would get lengths of those arrays to sort by!)

---

In my understanding your hash to sort is like

```
$VAR1 = {
    '0x00000008' => [ 'atgdb003f_avg01,hdisk10,atgdb003f_ovg01,...' ],
    ...
}
```

where each value is an arrayref with exactly one element.